# SQL query to display column values as column name in table

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I  have a field name 'Title' from table 'Greeting'. Title field in UI might come as FirstName or LastName or combination of both.

Greeting table looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Collapsed Borders</h2>
<p>If you want the borders to collapse into one border, add the CSS border-collapse property.</p>

<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>FirstName</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LastName</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>nickName</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>preferredName</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to write a SQL Query to find which has Title FirstName only, LastName only and both FirstName and LastName and display in below table format.
Create column name as FirstName and lastName and indicate by 'Yes' if that displayed and 'No' if not displayed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Collapsed Borders</h2>
<p>If you want the borders to collapse into one border, add the CSS border-collapse property.</p>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I wrote below query and got the individual information of the 'Title' but not able to get column values as table column name format. Could you please help me to get output data in that table format

```
Select distinct Title from Greeting  WHERE  Title in ('FirstName','LastName') 
Select distinct Title from Greeting  WHERE  Title ='FirstName'
Select distinct Title from Greeting  WHERE  Title = 'LastName'
```

Comment: Please look into the 'pivot' operation.  Pivoting might help here.

Comment: can you paste your sample database data and what you want it to look like pls

Comment: Thank you @JosephDoggie

Comment: I only skimmed, but are you looking for the literal strings `FirstName` and `LastName`? Or are those column values?

Comment: @barrycarter those are just the column values not literal strings

Comment: Then they don't belong in quotes. (some SQL servers let you them in backticks, but not single quotes)

Comment: Thank you @JosephDoggie . I tried 'pivot' and that helped me to get  get output data in that table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried 'pivot' and that helped me to get  get output data in that table format